# CosmosDB Throughput Database Level vs Container Level

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are using `com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark` library from Databricks to `bulk` write into CosmosDB Containers.

Currently throughput's are set on container (5 containers) level (ex: **10000** RUs).  Sometime couple of write operations on a given container throttle's as RUs consumed are  100%, but after re-tries does finish.  Load into the containers are in **Parallel**.

What if we change throughput to database level (ex: **50000** RUs - equally distributed among the containers) and execute write process in **sequence**.  Will container into which data is being written will have access to **50000** RUs or **10000** RUs?

Comment: You have to choose, for a container, whether to dedicate throughput or to use shared database throughput. There's no combining. So if you use db-level provisioning with a container, you'd share the 50K RU/sec you configured at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cosmos containers that are configured in autopilot mode have the following benefits:

- **Simple** – There is no need to invest time in manually scaling throughput or writing code to automatically scale throughput
- **Reliable** – Autopilot scaling is fully managed by Microsoft. There is no disruption to client connections, applications, or impact to SLA’s.
- **No rate-limiting of operations** – Rate limiting (throttled requests) will not happen if throughput consumed is within the max throughput chosen for autopilot mode.

By default, the distribution will be done according to the RU's when we are using Container level throughput.

If we need to manually provide assignment, it can be done to handle total 50K RU's, but it is not cost-effective and also not a great approach to follow.

**Autopilot mode pricing:**

**- Single-region write accounts-** Cost for provisioned RU’s is 50% higher

**- Multi-region write accounts-** Cost for provisioned RU’s is identical to cost of manually provisioned throughput RU’s

Comment: Autopilot is now called as Autoscale

Autoscale was previously known as “autopilot”.  

A minimum of 1,000 RU/s must be provisioned for autoscale provisioned throughput, which will scale hourly between 400 and 4,000 RU/s depending on usage